# Заполнение foreign key в дочерней таблице в соответсвии со значением из родительской

Tags: java, sql, h2

В базе данных *H2* есть две таблицы: employees и department.

В employees есть поля: `ID`, `DEPARTMENT`, `FULLNAME`, `DEPARTMENT_ID`.

В department: `ID`, `DEPARTMENT`.

*Foreign key* проставлен для `department.ID - employees.DEPARTMENT_ID`.

Хочу сделать так, что бы при добавлении нового сотрудника в таблицу, в поле `DEPARTMENT_ID` автоматически проставлялось значение, равное значению поля `ID` в таблице department для соответствующих `DEPARTMENT` в обеих таблицах.

Каким образом это можно реализовать?

На данный момент у меня есть такой запрос:

```
insert into employees(fullName, department) values(:fullName, :department)
```

и метод:

```
@Value("${query.insertNewEmployee}")
private String insertNewEmployee;

@Override
public void insertNewEmployee(String fullName, String department) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(2);
    map.put("fullName", fullName);
    map.put("department", department);
    jdbcTemplate.update(insertNewEmployee, map);
}
```

Comment: Не понимаю задачи,что вы хотите сделать? У вас связь один ко многим, в одном отделе трудятся несколько сотрудников. Как вы собираетесь автоматически проставлять отдел при добавлении нового сотрудника, их же много и нужно выбрать конкретный. Если есть gui, делайте комбобокс с выбором отдела.

Comment: Видимо, не совсем корректно описал вопрос я. Отдел выбирается мануально. Автоматически, в соответствии с выбранным отделом, нужно чтоб проставлялось department_id поле

Comment: Тогда понятно, первое что сразу в глаза бросается у вас в таблице Employees  хранится department - название отдела и тут же ключ на отдел, так не делается. оставьте один ключ, иначе получается дублирование информации, а если нужно получать название отдела, делайте join двух таблиц:                                               `Select Employees.*,Department.department from Employees left join Department on  Employees.DEPARTMENT_ID = Department.ID`

Comment: Соответственно мануально проставляйте id, а не название отдела.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сделайте подзапрос, вместо:

```
insert into employees(fullName, department) values(:fullName, :department)
```

будет:

```
insert into employees(fullName, department) values(:fullName, (SELECT id FROM department.ID WHERE name = :department))
```